# Getting Permission denied while cross compiling a C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm, armcc

I installed gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8-2014.04_linux for cross compiling for arm-v8. but I am getting permission denied while building.
I used instruction:

```
gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8-2014.04_linux/gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ filename.cpp -o executableName
```

Comment: I guess that you don't have write permissions to the folder.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Either there was a problem installing the package, or you don't have write permission to the output file.

Comment: Error messege is Permission Denied

Answer (score 0):

Try with **sudo** for super user permission.

Comment: @Aptrij: Compiling as root is to be avoided; developing as root is to be avoided; actually, doing anything as root is to be avoided when possible.  It should not be necessary to use `sudo` to cross-compile code.  That it works is good, but it shows that there is a permissions problem of some sort that should be resolved.

Comment: Yeah! Exactly. You should either change the permissions of the directory or should use **sudo** everytime.

Comment: given sudo su once. so no need to give sudo everytime. Will check and change permission of the folder. Thanks Jonathan Lefler and ngrjs